# Google Maps Service Area Business - How many areas can I add?

Tags: google-maps, google-my-business

I am adding our business to Google Maps, and since we're a web shop I am selecting that "I deliver goods and services to customers within this area:

Now, there are two options. One is to set a radius around the business address, and Two is to add multiple cities/zip codes that we service.

There is no information regarding option two provided by Google other than:

> You will be able to set service areas based on the zip codes or cities
>   that you serve, or on a given area around your location.
>   [Source](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3038163?hl=en)

Since we service all of the world but focus on Asia, could we add multiple countries to this list and still appear in local searches done in those countries for the products we provide? Or should we limit this to just a few cities or a radius? There is no information about this, but it is possible to add multiple countries to the service area.